# Thread on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, multithreading, loading

I have a problem with running a thread on ICS 4.0.3

I made the apk and I have installed it both on 2.33 SE phone and Google Nexus S 4.0.3.

On SE the apk is running and loading as it's supposed to. However, on Nexus I am getting an error and I have for close it. But i see the program running behind. 
i have tried to remove the thread(loading screen, splash picture) from the code and run it again on Nexus, and it could run. So i discover my problem is on thread, onCreate thread starting. its any kind of difference from 2.33 to 4.0.3 ?

```
package my.LigTv.Browser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
public class LigTVBrowserActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


WebView mWebView;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 3000; // time to display the splash screen in ms
int progress = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);



    final Activity activity = this;

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait for the applet to load");

    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

    progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

    if(progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss(); 



    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {                 
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);

                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;                                                    
                        }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("my.LigTv.Browser.Starter"));
                stop();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}    

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _active = false;
    }
    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: Could you show us the stacktrace from the error that occurs?

Comment: @LeythHisham edit your Question and append it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `finish()` after starting the new activity. Also, why are you calling `stop()` on the thread? Once it has started the new activity, it will stop. This is an example I had already written, change as you wish:

```
            Runnable r1 = new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,Main.class));
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);
                            finish();

                        }
                    }, waitTime);
                }
            };
            runOnUiThread(r1);
```

Comment: Not to mention `stop()` is deprecated and should not be used at all.

Comment: ty very much, i fixet actually with my own code but u were right i dont know why i typed stop(), i remove it and now its working on 4.0.3 thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, I fixed it with another code as quick fix:

```
private Timer myTimer;
private int x=0;
private int interval=2500;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, interval);

}

private void TimerMethod()
{
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    if(x==1)
    {
        SplashActivity.this.finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
    }
    x++;
}
};
```

But without progress bar,

and if you want to do that when the user click on the splash screen he goes to the next activity, you can do that by canceling the timer and finishing the splash activity and go to the other.

Answer (score 0):

should't this be in ui thread..

```
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("my.LigTv.Browser.Starter"));
                stop();
});
```